# The simple recursive function doesn't work well

Tags: matlab, recursion

It's just an easy recursive function test.

It should stop at n = 3, but not.

Could you please tell me where is wrong in my code?

Thank you!

```
>> recursiveFunction(0)

   101

     1

g
   102

     1

g
   103

     1

     2

     3

     2

g
   103

     1

     2

     3

     3

g
   103

     1

     2

     3

     2

g
   102

     1

g
   103

     1

     2

     3

     2

g
   103

     1

     2

     3

     3

g
   103

     1

     2

     3

     3

g
   102

     1

g
   103

     1

     2

     3

     2

g
   103

     1

     2

     3

     3

g
   103

     1

     2

     3
```

```
function recursiveFunction(callHierarchie)
    callHierarchie = callHierarchie + 1;
    disp(callHierarchie + 100);
    for n = 1:3
        disp(n);
        if callHierarchie <= 2
            disp('g');
            recursiveFunction(callHierarchie);
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: The loop inside stops at 3, it can't do anything else. It is very unclear what you want your code to do and why you think it doesn't work. Please [edit] your question and try to clarify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is both how you're generating your output and how you're interpreting your output.  Here's a Python equivalent function that generates the same output:

```
def recursiveFunction1(callHierarchie):
    callHierarchie = callHierarchie + 1
    print("{:>6}".format(callHierarchie + 100))

    for n in range(1, 4):
        print("{:>6}".format(n))
        if callHierarchie <= 2:
            print('g')
            recursiveFunction(callHierarchie)

recursiveFunction(0)
```

Folks can verify it produces the same output.  Let's modify the code to indent based on the recursion level:

```
def recursiveFunction(callHierarchie):
    callHierarchie = callHierarchie + 1
    print(" " * callHierarchie, "{:>6}".format(callHierarchie + 100))

    for n in range(1, 4):
        print(" " * callHierarchie, "{:>6}".format(n))
        if callHierarchie <= 2:
            print(" " * callHierarchie, 'g')
            recursiveFunction(callHierarchie)
```

Now the output displays slightly differently:

```
% python3 test.py
     101
       1
  g
      102
        1
   g
       103
         1
         2
         3
        2
   g
       103
         1
         2
         3
        3
   g
       103
         1
         2
         3
       2
  g
      102
        1
   g
       103
         1
         2
         3
        2
   g
       103
         1
         2
         3
        3
   g
       103
         1
         2
         3
       3
  g
      102
        1
   g
       103
         1
         2
         3
        2
   g
       103
         1
         2
         3
        3
   g
       103
         1
         2
         3
%
```

You can see that `n` does stop at 3, but the extra numbers you were seeing were `n` at a different level of recursion!

Comment: Thank you very much! It's much clearer. It confuses me that after it starts to output "103", it still has "102" afterwards. So it seems that after the first whole inner loop, it jumps back to where callHierarchie = 2. I thought callHierarchie should be a global variable...